# Java. Реализация очереди

Tags: java, очередь

У меня есть код ( не мой ), в котором реализована очередь, с методом добавления и удаления элементов. Я не могу понять, зачем инициализировать поле rear как `rear = -1`? Как я думал, это из-за того, чтобы не выходить за пределы массива, но зачем его тогда сразу объявлять как rear = -1? Ведь первый элемент 0. А так же, строчка  в методе add(). Как оно работает ? Буду очень благодарен за объяснение.

```
queue[++rear] = elem;  //увеличение Rear и вставка
                                  nElem++;  // увеличение количества элементов в очереди
```

Код программы:

```
public class Queue {
private int[] queue;
private int maxSize; // максимальное количество элементов в очереди
private int nElem;  // текущее количество элементов в очереди
private int front;
private int rear;

public Queue(int maxSize) {
    this.maxSize = maxSize;
    queue = new int[maxSize];
    rear = -1;
    front = 0;
    nElem = 0;
}
public void add(int elem) {
    if (rear == maxSize - 1) {  // циклический перенос
        rear = -1;
    }

    queue[++rear] = elem;  //увеличение Rear и вставка
    nElem++;  // увеличение количества элементов в очереди
}
public int delete() {
    int temp = queue[front++]; // получаем первый элемент из очереди

    if (front == maxSize) { // циклический перенос
        front = 0;
    }
    nElem--; // уменьшаем количество элементов в очереди
    return temp;

}
public int getFront() {
    return queue[front];
}

public int getRear() {
    return queue[rear];
}

public boolean isFull() {
    return (nElem == maxSize - 1);
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    return (nElem == 0);
}

public int getSize() {
    return nElem;
}
```

Код Main:

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Queue myQueue = new Queue(5);

    myQueue.add(10);
    myQueue.add(20);
    myQueue.add(30);
    myQueue.add(40);
    myQueue.add(50);
    System.out.println(myQueue.toString());

    myQueue.delete();
    myQueue.delete();
    myQueue.delete();

    myQueue.add(60);

    while (!myQueue.isEmpty()) {
        int n = myQueue.delete();
        System.out.println("Elem: " + n);
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В методе `add` как раз у вас и происходит увеличение индекса в строке `queue[++rear] = elem;  //увеличение Rear и вставка`
Потому и при инициализации задано -1, при первом добавлении индекс сместиться на требуемые 0, так как `-1+1 = 0`

Comment: Аа блин, чет тупанул, спасибо!